# Integration by Substitution: Expectation with respect to transformed distribution

Tags: integration, probability-theory, probability-distributions, expected-value

## Problem

Suppose I have a random variable $z$ following a distribution $p(z)$. Suppose I have a transformation

$$
f(z) = x
$$

that transforms the random variable $z$ into a new random variable $x$ with distribution $p(x)$. I have often seen the following result

$$
\mathbb{E}_{p(x)}[g(x)] = \mathbb{E}_{p(z)}[g(f(z))].
$$

In other words, the expectation with respect to a distribution $p(x)$ can be written in terms of the original distribution $p(z)$.

Is there proof of this? I think this should work even if $f(z)$ is **not** invertible and/or differentiable.

## Tentative Solution

I suppose somehow one should use the integration by substitution with the mapping $z = f^{-1}(x)$. But not sure how to proceed to get the result above. In many of the comments below it has been noticed that this can be solved with measure theory. Would you mind showing me how it would work?

## Measure Theory Basics

Suppose we have two measurable spaces $(\Omega, \mathcal{F})$ and $(\mathsf{Z}, \mathcal{Z})$. The random variable $Z$ is a measurable mapping
$$
Z: \Omega \to \mathsf{Z}
$$

such that the pre-image $Z^{-1}(B)$ of any $\mathcal{Z}$-measurable set $B\in \mathcal{Z}$ is also $\mathcal{F}$-measurable:

$$
Z^{-1}(B) = \{\omega\in \Omega \, :\, Z(\omega) \in B \} \in \mathcal{F} \qquad \forall \, B \in \mathcal{Z}
$$
Now the distribution of $Z$ is a push-forward measure. Suppose we have a probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P})$. This means we can measure sets in $\mathcal{F}$. The push-forward or distribution for $Z$ is a way of measuring sets in $\mathcal{Z}$ via $\mathbb{P}$.

Basically, the distribution $Z_*\mathbb{P}$ assigns to sets $B\in\mathbb{Z}$ the same value as if we map $B$ back to $\mathcal{F}$ via $Z^{-1}$ first, and then we find its measure using $\mathbb{P}$.

$$
(\mathbb{P} \circ Z^{-1})(B) = Z_*\mathbb{P}(B)
$$

### My Attempt Using Measure Theory

Now, the new random variable $X$ is basically a function of the random variable $Z$ and therefore $X$ is also a random variable.

Consider the probability space $(\mathsf{Z}, \mathcal{Z}, Z_*\mathbb{P})$ for $Z$. Consider also a measurable function
$$
X: \mathsf{Z} \to \mathsf{X}
$$
where $(\mathsf{X}, \mathcal{X})$ is a measurable space. This essentially defines the random variable $X$. Since we can measure sets in $\mathcal{Z}$ using $Z_*\mathbb{P}$ we would like to measure sets in $\mathcal{X}$ too. To do this, we define the distribution of $X$ to be a push-forward measure. Essentially, to give a measure to a set $C\in \mathcal{X}$ it maps it to $\mathcal{Z}$ via $X^{-1}$ and then measures it with the distribution $Z_*\mathbb{P}$.

$$
(Z_*\mathbb{P} \circ X^{-1})(C) = X_*Z_*\mathbb{P}(C)
$$

Comment: Have you studied basic measure theory?

Comment: I know a little bit about the very basics: measures, measurable spaces, random variables, push-forward measures. Why?

Comment: It is nothing but push-forward of measures.

Comment: Your equation is just $\int g dP\circ f^{-1}=\int g\circ f dP$.

Comment: @Tobsn do you mind formalizing this a little bit? Since I'm a beginner in measure theory I really need the details to understand

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy does this equation have a name and where can I find it?

Comment: You just prove it first for simple functions using deifintion of the push forward measure $P\circ f^{-1}$ and then extend it to more general $g$.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Thank you! I tried writing up some measure theory above. I managed to construct the distribution for $X$. Is that correct?